# Why do Keras's evaluate_generator and evaluate report different accuracies on the same data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, keras

I'm using Keras's `ImageDataGenerator` and `flow_from_directory` to train a neural network.  The issue I'm having is that `evaluate_generator` and `evaluate` report different accuracies for the same data.  Here is a [minimal example](https://github.com/tinybike/keras-generator-minimal-example), which reports an accuracy of 0.24 from `evaluate_generator` but an accuracy of 0.44 from `evaluate`:

```py
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
import keras
import tensorflow as tf

np.random.seed(1)
tf.set_random_seed(1)

test_data_path = os.path.join("data", "test")

def load_data_from_image_files(base_data_path):
    X = []
    y = []
    for data_folder in os.listdir(base_data_path):
        data_folder_path = os.path.join(base_data_path, data_folder)
        if os.path.isdir(data_folder_path):
            for filename in os.listdir(data_folder_path):
                if filename.endswith(".jpg"):
                    X.append(cv2.imread(os.path.join(data_folder_path, filename)))
                    if data_folder == "null":
                        y.append([0])
                    else:
                        y.append([1])
    return np.array(X).astype("float32") / 255.0, np.array(y)

with open("model.json", "r") as json_file:
    model = keras.models.model_from_json(json_file.read())
model.load_weights("model.h5")
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])

X_test, y_test = load_data_from_image_files(test_data_path)
test_datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    test_data_path,
    target_size=(96, 96),
    batch_size=1,
    shuffle=False,
    class_mode="binary")
_, generator_test_accuracy = model.evaluate_generator(generator=test_generator, steps=test_generator.samples)
_, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print("evaluate_generator: %.3f, evaluate: %.3f" % (generator_test_accuracy, test_accuracy))
```

(This is [test.py](https://github.com/tinybike/keras-generator-minimal-example/blob/master/test.py) from the keras-generator-minimal-example repo.)  The pre-trained model loaded by this script is defined as follows:

```py
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(96, 96, 3)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(4, activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

The full script to set up and train the model is [here](https://github.com/tinybike/keras-generator-minimal-example/blob/master/train.py).

My question is, should `model.evaluate_generator` and `model.evaluate` in the above example report the same accuracy, or am I messing something up?  If I'm just missing a parameter or something, I'd greatly appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

---

Side note: [this Github issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6499) seems possibly related, although the various fixes proposed in that issue's comments don't fix the problem for me.  Setting `shuffle=False`, `workers=1`, and/or `max_queue_size=1` doesn't change anything, and setting `use_multiprocessing=True` causes a bunch of the following errors to appear in my terminal and the script hangs up:

```
/home/jack/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py:616: UserWarning: The input 0 could not be retrieved. It could be because a worker has died.
  UserWarning)
```

Since I haven't been able to resolve this secondary issue, I don't know if setting `use_multiprocessing=True` in `evaluate_generator` would resolve the issue I'm having with the accuracies not matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the discrepancy is caused by OpenCV's `imread` using BGR format, whereas Keras's `flow_from_directory` [expects RGB by default](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/image/directory_iterator.py#L71).  Reversing the channels to RGB resolved the issue.